# rendering strangely using both setstate and setvalue to modify an animate.value

Tags: react-native

react native 0.24.1
both ios and android

1. render a animate view with translateX = 0 binding in state
2. translateX setValue directly to make the view move left
3. try to setState translateX = 0, but the view still not return the 0 position

I made a mistake or it's a bug?
here is the code
thx

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      translateX : new Animated.Value(0),
      text : 80,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){

    setTimeout(()=>{
      //set animate value directly to move the view to left
      this.state.translateX.setValue(-20);
    },5000);


    setTimeout(()=>{
      //set animate value by setState
      //but the view is still at left
      this.setState({
        translateX : new Animated.Value(0),
        text:79
      });
    },10000)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop:48,flex:1}}>
        <Animated.View style={{transform:[{
          translateX : this.state.translateX
        }]}}>
              <View style={{backgroundColor:"red",alignItems:"center"}}><Text>{this.state.text}</Text></View>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
      )
    }
}
```